# How to use databinding with s:GridItemRenderer and anonymous objects?

Tags: data-binding, flex4, flex-spark, itemrenderer

I have a custom `s:GridItemRenderer` that contains a single `s:CheckBox` and is used to display a boolean property of the items in the grid's `dataProvider` which is dependend on which dataField was set for the column:

```
<s:GridItemRenderer>
    <s:CheckBox selected="{this.data[this.column.dataField]}"/>
</s:GridItemRenderer>
```

I can't (or rather: I don't want to) hardcode the property since I want to keep the renderer as generic as possible and hardcoding the property name would require me to write at least 2 otherwise identical renderers.

Now the problem is that the dataProvider contains only anonymous objects (e.g. `{foo:"blah", bar:"blubb", isBaz:true}`) and databinding doesn't work with hash lookups. Since the property name is not fixed but also dynamic, I cannot use the dot syntax to access the property on the objects.

I've already searched the web for a possible solution, but didn't find any that worked. I tried using an `mx:ObjectProxy` as a wrapper for the data item [as suggest here](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/09/27/detecting-changes-to-an-object-using-the-flex-objectproxy-class/) but that didn't work. I tried manually creating the binding with `mx:BindingUtils.bindProperty()` [as suggested here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/56024/Flex-Data-Binding-Tricks) but that didn't work either.

Is there any way to achieve databinding in that situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During some refactoring the structure of the `dataProvider` changed and I was required to write specific `itemRenderers` for each datagrid, so the generic approach is no longer supported and the issue basically resolved itself. :)